# Using Redirect in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Im having trouble using redirect functionality within my spring boot application. As shown in my code below im returning "redirect:/aucConfirm/" but when i initiate this i get a "This application has no explicit mapping" error.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class WelcomeController {

    @Autowired
    AuctionItemRepository aucRepository;

// inject via application.properties
@Value("${welcome.message:test}")
private String message = "Hello World";

@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public String welcome(Map<String, Object> model) {
    model.put("message", this.message);
    return "welcome";
}


    @RequestMapping(value = "/sell", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addAuction(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {


        model.addAttribute("newAuction", new AuctionItem());

        return "NewAuction";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/sell", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String saveAuction(@ModelAttribute AuctionItem newAuction, RedirectAttributes attributes){


        return "redirect:/aucConfirm";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/aucConfirm", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String confirmNewAuction(Model model, HttpServletRequest request) {


        return "aucConfirm";
    }
}
```

This is my current configuration class -

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan
@EnableJpaRepositories("All")
@EntityScan("All")
public class AuctionWebApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer  {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(AuctionWebApplication.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(AuctionWebApplication.class, args);
}

    @Bean
    DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/auctiondb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull");
        dataSource.setUsername("root");
        dataSource.setPassword("toor");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManager.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManager.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManager.setPackagesToScan("All");

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings", "false");
        entityManager.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

        return entityManager;
    }
```

}

*Update*

Could it possibly have something to do with my jsp page that im trying to establish the recommit? I have a mvc form here -

```
<mvc:form class="form-inline" action="${action}" method="post" modelAttribute="newAuction" id="addNewAuc">
```

and when the user hits the next button it should hit the "redirect:/aucConfirm" -

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success" form="addNewAuc">Next</button>
```

Is there anything wrong with this code? Im running out of ideas at this point. Do i need to add anything to my spring boot configuration class to get it working? - Please help!

*Update 2*

http://localhost:8080/AuctionWebsite/sell
[image]

When i enter details int this form and select next i want it to redirect to-
http://localhost:8080/AuctionWebsite/aucConfirm

However this is what appears-

[image]

not redirecting at all and remaining with link http://localhost:8080/AuctionWebsite/sell

http://localhost:8080/AuctionWebsite/aucConfirm works when entered manually

Im getting a little bit desperate at this point, would really appreciate any help.

Comment: try "redirect:aucConfirm"; . Can you confirm what's the url it is redirecting to.

Comment: @yogidilip this didnt solve my problem, see update for more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code

```
redirect:aucConfirm
```

Instead of

```
redirect:/aucConfirm
```

As per your updated question. it seems that

> "This application has no explicit mapping" error

Is for /error url;

The actual error is

> Validation failed for object 'auctionItem'

So problem is not with redirection , it is something else related to validation. You may find specific error on console log.

Comment: could you paste the url you are getting for this. full url

Comment: ive updated my original post within update 2, http://localhost:8080/AuctionWebsite/aucConfirm is the url i would like to redirect to @Dhiraj

Answer (score 0):

I could not get this to work (with or without a '/' after the ':')...

```
@PostMapping("/customer/update")
public String customerUpdate(Customer customer) {
    customerRepository.save(customer);
    return "redirect:customer/list";        
}
```

...so went with this...

```
@PostMapping("/customer/update")
public RedirectView customerUpdate(Customer customer) {
    customerRepository.save(customer);
    return new RedirectView("/customer/list");      
}
```