# Redirect from Spring REST controller with parameters

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I have two different Spring applications (app-one, app-two), app-one should receive a response and then **redirect to app-two with some parameters**. So, I have the following REST controller in app-one:

```
@RestController
public class RedirectController
{
    @GetMapping(value = "/redirect")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> redirectEndpoint(HttpServletRequest request, 
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)
    {
        // Do some business logic

        // Set parameters
        redirectAttributes.addAttribute("attribute", "Value 1");
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("flashAttribute", "Value 2");

        // Redirect to success URL
        String redirectURL = "http://app-two/success";
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setLocation(URI.create(redirectURL));
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FOUND).headers(headers).build();
    }
}
```

And the following REST controller in app-two:

```
@RestController
public class SuccessController
{
    @GetMapping(value = "/success")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> successEndpoint(HttpServletRequest request, Model model,
        @RequestParam(value = "attribute", required = false) String attribute,
        @ModelAttribute(value = "flashAttribute") String flashAttribute)
    {
        // Get parameters
        System.out.println("attribute: " + attribute);
        System.out.println("flashAttribute: " + flashAttribute);

        String flashAttributeFromModelMap = (String) model.asMap().get("flashAttribute");
        System.out.println("flashAttributeFromModelMap: " + flashAttributeFromModelMap);

        Map<String, ?> flashMap = RequestContextUtils.getInputFlashMap(request);
        if (flashMap != null)
        {
            String flashAttributeFromFlashMap = (String) flashMap.get("flashAttribute");
            System.out.println("flashAttributeFromFlashMap: " + flashAttributeFromFlashMap);
        }

        // Do some business logic

        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).build();
    }
}
```

I was able to redirect successfully by returning `FOUND` (302). But when adding attributes to `RedirectAttributes` (in this case `attribute` and `flashAttribute`), these attributes are not found after the redirection done (`attribute` gets `null` and `flashAttribute` gets `empty`).

I tried to get the attributes values by different ways (`@RequestParam`, `@ModelAttribute`, `model.asMap().get()`, and `RequestContextUtils.getInputFlashMap(request).get()`) but none of them gets the correct value.

What I need is to get the correct attributes' values in `successEndpoint`. Any suggestions on how to accomplish that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't this `http://app-two/success` be `http://your_server:port_number/app-two/success`

Comment: debug the `build()` on the `ResponseEntity` to see if it does get the atttribute as a query param in the URI. Also I from what I am reading the flashAttributes, the data is stored on the session so that would not be present in `app-two` as its going to be different JVM.

Comment: @NicholasK, no this is not a problem and the redirection done successfully

Comment: @Yogesh_D, no it does not get the `attribute` as a query param in the URI and actually this is the problem! I think you are right about `flashAttribute`, it is a different JVM and that is why it is not present in `app-two`.

Comment: @ maybe try a different way to redirect, see @https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43103809/using-redirect-in-spring-boot

Comment: or just add the query param yourself.

Comment: @Yogesh_D, I already do this and add the query params to the `redirectURL` manually but I believe this is not the best solution.